# `if` con un boolean que no actua segun la documentacion

Tags: java, if

Estoy trabajando contra un Active Directory y la respuesta del servidor es un boolean. Y siempre, siempre, entra en la parte "true" del if.

He hecho debug devuelve `false` haya ido bien o mal la validación contra el Active Directory.

Siendo que el resultado es false, ¿no debería ir al else?

La parte de mi código:

```
if(callLDAP(internalVO));//este metodo devuelve un boolean
    System.out.println("Entra en el true");
}else{
    System.out.println("Entra en el false");
}
```

El codigo de `callLDAP` es esto básicamente:

```
private static boolean callLDAP(InternalDoLoginVO internalVO){
    boolean status = false;
    String LDAPServer = "servidor";
    String LDAPPort = "puerto";
    String LDAPDomain = "dominio";
    String LDAPUser = internalVO.getUser();
    String LDAPassword = internalVO.getPass();

    LDAPServer LDAP = new LDAPServer(LDAPServer, LDAPPort, LDAPDomain); 
    LDAP.setCredentials(LDAPUser, LDAPassword);
    status = LDAP.doLogin();//haciendo debug esta variable es false
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Te falta una llave en el if. Tienes un punto y coma en su lugar

```
if(callLDAP(internalVO)){//este metodo devuelve un boolean
    System.out.println("Entra en el true");
}else{
    System.out.println("Entra en el false");
}
```

Comment: Me fustigaría con un bate de baseball con clavos oxidados.... Casi una hora de volverme loco leyendo el codigo, documentación, la documentación por parte del servidor al que apunto.... Muchas gracias! En 5 min te acepto como respuesta correcta, que aún no deja

Comment: De nada. A todos nos han pasado cosas similares alguna vez.

Comment: JDev gracias por mencionar el error pero recuerda que para este tipo de solución, lo apropiado es comentarlo bajo la pregunta y votar para el cierre de la misma por el motivo "No relacionado ->  fallo tipografico". Un saludo